# Advance where in laravel jenssegers

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

My document in mongodb database is like below

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("545a20208e227b4c42601601"),
   "polish": NumberLong(3),
   "symmetry": NumberLong(1),
   "certy_no": "6175554509",
   "certy_name": "541bfa1d3d1784380600002f",
   "desc": "Fancy Intense Yellow",
   "intensity": NumberLong(6), 
   "price": NumberLong(4000),
   "weight": 1.04,
}
```

Now i want to query like **"price * weight >2000"**

So how this is possible in laravel in jenssegers.

Thanks --ND

Answer (score 0):

## Query Builder

> **The database driver plugs right into the original query builder.** When
>   using mongodb connections, you will be able to build fluent queries to
>   perform database operations. For your convenience, there is a
>   collection alias for table as well as some additional mongodb specific
>   operators/operations.

I am going to give this a good guess. But try this and let me know how it goes.

```
$results = SomeClass::where('(price * weight)', '>', 2000)->get();
```

Comment: Boss i am using mongodb.

Comment: I know that jenssegers integrates with laravel's query builder and eloquent ORM. jenssegers is simply a mongodb driver for laravel.